# Calling Partial Views in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, razor, umbraco

I have a question that seems to be driving me mad. How can I pull a partial view from another master into my home page (which is not related to the view, etc.) and is in another folder? I just want to reference:

`@Html.ThemedPartial(Model, "Latest")`

(which is from the Articulate blog in Umbraco). However, I am not sure how to do this because I do not know what using directives to include, etc.?

Is there an easy way to do this?

I'm receiving the following error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper>' does not contain a definition for 'ThemedPartial' and no extension method 'ThemedPartial' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It is quoting the source error at `@Html.ThemedPartial(Model, "Latest")`

I also tried `@Html.Partial("~/App_Plugins/Articulate/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Partials/Latest.cshtml", Model)` instead of `@Html.ThemedPartial(Model, "Latest")` with no luck. I am getting the following:

> Umbraco.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingException: Cannot bind source content type Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.Index to model type Articulate.Models.IMasterModel.

Comment: What do you mean "another master"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Razor. I have a blog that operates from a master with many partial views. I am trying to include one of the partial views (@Html.ThemedPartial(Model, "Latest")) in my website's cshtml home page. Therefore, I am trying to call a partial view into a totally different .cshtml file.

Comment: Partials by definition are in a totally different cshtml file. I don't see what the problem you're facing is. What happens if you try to run it now? Do you get an error?

Comment: Why did you use `ThemedPartial`? Where did you get that?

Comment: It's from a blog engine in umbraco called Articulate. I have been using ThemedPartial to call partial views in the Articulate Model. But now I am trying to call it in a new Content Model...I'm not too experienced with MVC...sorry for the inexperience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/Recent.cshtml", Model)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the [Articulate sourcecode](https://github.com/Shazwazza/Articulate) you'll see ThemedPartial is just an extension method that does the following:

```
var path = PathHelper.GetThemePartialViewPath(model, partialName);
return html.Partial(path, viewModel, viewData);
```

Where GetThemePartialViewPath returns a relative path to the view

The following should work if you set the @model declaration of Latest.cshtml correctly

`@Html.Partial("~/App_Plugins/Articulate/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Partials/Latest.cshtml", Model)`

Comment: What do you mean set the model declaration correctly...it is declared as: (at)using Articulate
(at)using Articulate.Models
(at)inherits UmbracoViewPage<Articulate.Models.IMasterModel>

Comment: `inherits UmbracoViewPage<Articulate.Models.IMasterModel>` Means the partial view is expecting a model of type IMasterModel. Are you passing a model that implements this interface?